# Setting setOnClickListener on a Button in a View Stub

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, viewstub

I'm creating a View Stub for my login screen, however I have a question. When I try to set an `setOnClickListener` on my login button in my `viewstub_login.kt` file, the button action won't go through. Do I need to change my extension on my Kotlin file, or do I need to put my `setOnClickListener` in the `onStart()` function? Thank you!

**viewstub_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BF090909">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/loginCardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/main_purple"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoLoginImageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/login_logo_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/skedaddle_services_"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoLoginImageView">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailInputTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_underlinr"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/outline_mail_white_24"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/e_mail"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_underlinr"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/outline_lock_white_24"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordTextInputLayout" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondLoginButton"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/forgotPasswordButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/secondLoginButton"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:background="@color/main_teal"
                android:text="@string/log_in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cancelButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancelButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cancelButton"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**viewstub_login.kt**

```
class LoginViewStub : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.viewstub_login)

        val emailTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.emailInputTextView)
        val passwordTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.passwordTextInputView)
        val forgetPasswordButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.forgotPasswordButton)
        val loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.secondLoginButton)
        val cancelButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelButton)

        val emailText = emailTextView.text
        val passwordText = passwordTextView.text

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (emailText.isEmpty(emailTextView.text) || passwordText.isEmpty(passwordTextView.text)) {
                val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Please fill out all fields.").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Okay", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                    dialog, id -> finish()
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                    dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                })

                val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                alert.show()
            }
        }

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener {

        }

        forgetPasswordButton.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

}

private fun Boolean.isEmpty(str: CharSequence?): Boolean {
    return str == null || str.length == 0
}
```

Comment: I think that you meant to do with `if (emailText === null &&...` is check whether the text is either null or empty, not the view itself.

Comment: @HenryTwist, how can I show the alert? And the view's buttons aren't being able to be selected either.

Comment: Maybe focus on one problem at a time, have you managed to modify the checks so that they check the text, not the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click listener is correct, but inside the block, your code is not correct
because emailText and passwordText is not null, as you have defined above, thus the if condition returning false and your code just going over it

Comment: How do I check if the text is empty? Because I want to show an alert if the text is empty.

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(emailInputTextView.getText())

Comment: replace "emailText === null && passwordText === null" with "emailText.isEmpty() || passwordText.isEmpty()"

Comment: @Noah or @MriDx, added what I thought was correct. Should I be creating the `isEmpty()` function at the bottom of my `LoginViewStub.kt`?

Comment: Got it, thanks @MriDx, had to put functionality in my `WelcomeActivity.kt`